# Install Ubuntu 20.04 (64 bit) in virtual box hangs on install screens

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox

### What I am doing

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 (64 bit) in a virtual box.

### Problem

Installation hangs on various screens:

- Sometimes on Language selection (first screen after choosing "install Ubuntu")
- Sometimes on "Who are you" (clicking log-in radio buttons is ok, but focussing text boxes is impossible)
- Sometimes after "continue"-click in partitioning dialog.

### What I tried

For Ubuntu 19.04, I could use safe graphics mode(?), that would install from a console-like installation screen (no fancy gui). That way it worked. However, using "safe graphics mode", doesn't help now. Besides, it's exactly the same screens as without "safe graphics".

### Host

XUbuntu 19.10 (64 bit)

### Guest

- 1GB RAM
- 10GB HDD
- 

Answer (score 0):

Increase VM settings:

- RAM: 2GB
- HDD: 20GB

Comment: I am experiencing a similar issue with both Ubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 10 host with 16GB of RAM allocated to the VM and with 50GB of fixed size SSD drive file.

Comment: Mybe try to install in console mode ( if you happen to get it work --> freenode.org #ubuntu )